# System hotkeys can't be used during fullscreen Pygame window

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I am trying to make a fullscreen game in Python out of Pygame. My problem is, I can't use the command+tab Mac system key combination (which is tab out) while in full screen. I also can't hide it. This is my code:

```
display = (1440,900)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

I've tried using `pygame.display.iconify()` to hide and minimize the window in order to tab out of the program, but it doesn't work in fullscreen because instead it creates a fullscreen black window. I also don't want to toggle fullscreen while doing this.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an instance of a [known issue](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/203) with pygame. A similar problem is [described](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/203#issuecomment-289297874) there:

> Also when I Cmd+Tab through windows - it's not there. That's why I
>   have to swipe up to see to four-finger-swipe-up […]

[Apparently there was a fix](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/203#issuecomment-372390169):

> I committed a fix in [#415](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/415).
>
> If you [Compile from source](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile#Installing%20from%20source%20with%20homebrew) you can try it out.
>
> ```
> pip install https://github.com/pygame/pygame/archive/master.zip
> ```
>
> Otherwise, it should be in [pygame 1.9.4](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/390).

You could try this and see if it applies to your problem.

Comment: I received keyboard inputs inside pygame, but the system (not pygame) does not recognize the combinations such as command+tab when pygame window is full-screened.